# SFTP with sudo as different user and passwordless connection

Tags: sudo, sftp, file-transfer

I have a batch job that runs as local user. I have a requirement to sftp files as part of the same job but with sudo in as different AD user.

To achieve this, the AD user has been setup on source server and below configurations have been performed in the sudoers file to enable any user within ADMINSUDO group to perform scp/sftp

```
Cmnd_Alias TSTSFTP = /usr/bin/scp, /usr/bin/sftp
%ADMINSUDO ALL=(AD_User) NOPASSWD:SETENV:TSTSFTP
```

when I execute

```
sudo -u AD_User /usr/bin/sftp
```

I get below error which indicates sudo is successful but can any one help with the sftp?

```
usage: sftp [-1246aCfpqrv] [-B buffer_size] [-b batchfile] [-c cipher]
          [-D sftp_server_path] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit]
          [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-R num_requests] [-S program]
          [-s subsystem | sftp_server] host
       sftp [user@]host[:file ...]
       sftp [user@]host[:dir[/]]
       sftp -b batchfile [user@]host
```

Answer (score 1):

host is a mandatory argument to sftp

use

```
sudo -u AD_User /usr/bin/sftp host
```

note that

- `AD_user` should be able to read local file if sending, write them if receiving
- `host` must accept password less connexion from `AD_user` (I expect this is why you use `sudo` in first place)

Comment: Thanks @Archemar. I tried above with the hostname but it prompted for password. if the sudo is working then it should have gone in without the password.

Comment: which password ? local one or distant one  ? from memory `/etc/sudoers` syntax is `NOPASSWD:SETENV TSTSFTP` (only one `:`)